# Remove/ redirect part of url string (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some duplicate urls with some parts I would like to remove (redirect).

For example: http://www.mydomain.dk/tryksager?pop=0

I would like to remove the `?pop=0` and 301 redirect to: http://www.mydomain.dk/tryksager

This is so that google will not use the `?pop=0`. It needs to work on all pages the have the `?pop=0` part in it.

Comment: what have you already tried? And do you have any other rules in your.htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just removing the query string, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pop.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.mydomain.dk/tryksager? [L]
```

It can be `pop` or any other label. Important to define it, though. Otherwise it will remove all queries.

**UPDATED:**

Assuming `pop` is the constant, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pop.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.mydomain.dk/$1? [L]
```

Comment: @ Felipe
Your method works, but is it posible to make it work for all urls and not only /tryksager  ?

Comment: EDIT: Your method takes urls including ?pop=0  to the url /tryksager

I have other urls with ?pop=0
/diverse/visitkort?pop=0

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should [**accept**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.